# How to keep track of anonymous session in Django and React

Tags: reactjs, django, session

I have a cart in django that uses session to track the user. The cart is created when the user adds an item to cart, also checks if the cart existed by session id. But when I run an add to cart mutation in react, Django creates a new cart every time.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.